# PLSQL - ORA-01008 - Not all variables bound

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, function-call

i'm trying to CALL a very simple PLSQL function and i can't guess what i'm doing wrong:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY KYC_OWN.KYCK_TEMP IS

FUNCTION PrintHelloWorld RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
  RETURN 'Hello World'; 
END printHelloWorld;

END KYCK_TEMP;
```

Then i call the function like this:

```
call   KYC_OWN.KYCK_TEMP.PrintHelloWorld() INTO :x;
```

I guess i need to declare the x variable somewhere, but how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY KYC_OWN.KYCK_TEMP IS

FUNCTION PrintHelloWorld RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
  RETURN ('Hello World'); 
END printHelloWorld;

END KYCK_TEMP;
```

or create a variable like below and return g_helloworld

```
create or replace package constants as
g_helloworld constant varchar2(11) := 'Hello World';
function get_helloworld return varchar2;
end constants;

/
create or replace package body constants as
function get_helloworld return varchar2
is
begin
    return g_helloworld;
end get_helloworld;
end constants;
```

/

Comment: thanks, i tried the first option you suggested me but i still can't call the function using call   KYC_OWN.KYCK_TEMP.PrintHelloWorld() INTO :x;

Answer (score 0):

If you're in SQL*Plus, you could create a variable and then use that to hold the function return variable, e.g.:

```
VARIABLE x varchar2(30)
call   KYC_OWN.KYCK_TEMP.PrintHelloWorld() INTO :x;
print x
```

or you could simply use an anonymous block, along with dbms_output to display the number:

```
set serveroutput on -- assuming you're in SQL*Plus
declare
  v_val varchar2(30);
begin
  v_val := KYC_OWN.KYCK_TEMP.PrintHelloWorld;
  dbms_output.put_line('return val = '||v_val);
end;
```